# How to make music play in background of batch game

Tags: batch-file

I am making a batch game in notepad and I was wondering how I can play the file music in the background.

I have this:

```
@echo off
start Music.mp3
Pause
```

What this does is it starts my music named Music.mp3 but it starts it in a separate window that pops up. What I want is for it to start playing, but not pop up in a window. I also want it to start and play in the background as I play my game.

Any ways I could do this?

Comment: `start /min` is the closest you can get in pure batch.

Comment: you can use any command-line mp3 player https://www.google.com/search?q=console+mp3+player+windows, start it when you need and stop it by taskkill

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The closest your can get using internal commands of a command processor can only minimize a window. If you really want to "background" it, the script will be long and confusing.

```
start /min /c "" Music.mp3
```

Alternatively this:

```
@echo off
set "file=track12.mp3"
( echo Set Sound = CreateObject("WMPlayer.OCX.7"^)
  echo Sound.URL = "%file%"
  echo Sound.Controls.play
  echo do while Sound.currentmedia.duration = 0
  echo wscript.sleep 100
  echo loop
  echo wscript.sleep (int(Sound.currentmedia.duration^)+1^)*1000) >sound.vbs
cscript.exe //nologo sound.vbs
```

This creates a `vbs` that starts the music without a new window.

---

User Lưu Vĩnh Phúc has suggested, using a hybrid script prevents the issue of cleaning up.

```
@echo off

rem ----START OF BATCH CODE---
rem You can paste your entire batch code down here, and use
rem the cscript command whenever you want to play the sound.

cscript //nologo "%~f0?.wsf" //job:VBS

rem ----END OF BATCH CODE---

<package>
  <job id="JS"> 
    <script language="VBScript">

       Set Sound = CreateObject("WMPlayer.OCX.7")
       Sound.URL = "%file%"
       Sound.Controls.play
       do while Sound.currentmedia.duration = 0
       wscript.sleep 100
       loop
       wscript.sleep (int(Sound.currentmedia.duration)+1)*1000)

  </script>
</job>
```

Comment: Thanks! My only question is in your code it says:         Set "file=track12.mp3".               The file=track12 do I replace that with my MP3 file?

Comment: Correct. Change that to whatever your like.

Comment: Also note this may not work on newer Windows(I haven't tested this yet, but Windows Media player seems to be gone in Wind 10)

Comment: Ok I will do that

Comment: Do I save this as .vbs?

Comment: No, just paste this in where you want to play this music, and you are good to go.

Comment: a [hybrid vbs-batch](https://ss64.com/vb/syntax-hybrid.html) would be better and you don't need to clean the vbs file later

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc Just added the hybrid solution.

Answer (score 1):

[**Here's another**](https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/master/hybrids/jscript/mediarunner.bat) script based on `WMPlayer.OCX`.You can use it like:

```
mediarunner.bat Music.mp3
```

[**Here's one**](https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/master/hybrids/mshta/soundPlayer.bat) based on the `bgsound` tag in internet explorer.It allows you also to set sound volume as parameter.Does not require installed media player unlike WMPlayer.OCX approach:

```
soundPlayer.bat Music.mp3 -50
```

[**One based on SP objects**](https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/master/hybrids/jscript/spplayer.bat) though unfortunately it can play only wav files:

```
spplayer.bat file.wav
```

None of the script creates temp files.

Answer (score 1):

You can also play online music like this script :

```bat
@echo off
Title Listen to the music with batch and vbscript
mode con cols=60 lines=3 & color 9E
echo.
Echo           To stop the music just close this window 
set "file=https://stream.initialradio.fr:8443/djbuzz-192k.mp3"
set "vbsfile=%tmp%\%~n0.vbs"
( 
    echo Set Sound = CreateObject("WMPlayer.OCX.7"^)
    echo Sound.URL = "%file%"
    echo Sound.Controls.play
    echo do while Sound.currentmedia.duration = 0
    echo wscript.sleep 100
    echo loop
    echo wscript.sleep (int(Sound.currentmedia.duration^)+1^)*1000
)>%vbsfile%
cscript /nologo %vbsfile%
```

Comment: Hey, I find another odd thing in your script. `/nologo` should be `//nologo`. But these two both works...

Answer (score 0):

I'm developing a batch game myself at the moment, and have worked out a similar solution of my own, that allows alot of flexibility in terms of flow of music, sound effects, volume etc, Without the player ever being visible.

The one thing that frustrated me the most though was devising a system to stop the music player if the user exited the game without using a quit option to call the taskill used to end the vbs script and it's Child processes.

I ended up devising  a vbs script that monitors the cmd.exe and calls the cleanup/Taskkill program when there's no cmd.exe process active.

All the music control happens as a background process, so there's only ever one instance of cmd.exe running for the games operation.

There is advantage to creating your vbs scripts to control settings from your batch, as you can use parameters to pass information on which track, what volume, and whether to loop the sound / music or not. Because volume is sent as a parameter when music or sounds are played, this opens up Volume and Sound options for the player such as effectively muting sound effects and setting the volume of the music to taste - or disabling one or both.

The code for my solution is Documented and described here:
    https://pastebin.com/nm01MzhM

An extract of the music player script:

```
(
echo Set Sound = CreateObject("WMPlayer.OCX.7"^)
echo Sound.URL = "%~1"
echo Sound.settings.volume = %~2
echo Sound.settings.setMode "loop", %~3
echo Sound.Controls.play
echo While Sound.playState ^<^> 1
echo      WScript.Sleep 100
echo Wend
)>PlayMusic.vbs

start /min PlayMusic.vbs
```

And can be heard (and seen) in effect [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DuzQ_lXwegg)

Answer (score 0):

I am Developing my own game, and it uses a series of different Audio types, including speech, music and sound effects.

```
<!-- : Begin batch script
@echo off
mode con COLS=55 LINES=40
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
color f0
title Flame Eternal
set drive=%~dp0%
CALL :MACROS
%music:t s=Music (entersongname here, no extension)%
pause
call :TIP
::^^call :tip kills the process playing music, but not the batch script
:: When you close down the batch game, the music stops

::Here is how the Talking happens:
SET voice=START /B CSCRIPT //NOLOGO "%~f0?.wsf" //JOB:Voice "%talk%" Û
%voice:Û=0%
::^^^^^^^^YOu need the %voice:Û=0%underneath the command. Where it says %talk%, just put the sentence you want read.

::for sfx, use 
%music:t s=sound (entersongname here, no extension)%
::Do not put .mp3 at the end :-)


:TIP
TASKKILL /F /IM CSCRIPT.exe >NUL
GOTO :EOF

:MACROS
SET music=START /B CSCRIPT //NOLOGO "%~f0?.wsf" //JOB:t s.mp3
SET ^"LF=^

^" Above empty line is required - do not remove

GOTO :EOF
----- Begin wsf script --->
<package>
  <job id="Sound">
    <script language="VBScript">
      Set args = WScript.Arguments
      Set Sound = CreateObject("WMPlayer.OCX.7")
      Sound.URL = args.Item(0)
      Sound.Controls.play
      do while Sound.currentmedia.duration = 0
      Wscript.sleep 100
      loop
      Wscript.sleep (int(Sound.currentmedia.duration)+1)*1000
    </script>
  </job>
  <job id="Music">
    <script language="VBScript">
      Set args = WScript.Arguments
      Set Sound = CreateObject("WMPlayer.OCX.7")
      Sound.URL = args.Item(0)
      Sound.settings.volume = 100
      Sound.settings.setMode "loop", True
      Sound.Controls.play
      While Sound.playState <> 1
      WScript.Sleep 100
      Wend
    </script>
  </job>
  <job id="Voice">
    <script language="VBScript">
      Option Explicit
      Dim SpeakV, args
      Set args = WScript.Arguments
      Set SpeakV = CreateObject("SAPI.spVoice")
      Set SpeakV.Voice = SpeakV.GetVoices.Item (args.Item(1))
      SpeakV.Speak args.Item(0)
    </script>
  </job>
</package>
```

If the Music file is in any drive, C:, D:\ etc, just do this:

```
set drive=%cd:~0,2%
cd %drive%\Dude\Desktop
 ::or if the file is in a subdirectory, like a music folder on your desktop:

cd "%~dp0%\Music"
```